# How to add Admob after 200 words in my variable {content}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello everyone I made an application and I would like to add an admob in the content of my variable content after each 200 words someone have ideas for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const text = getMyText().split(' ');
    const chunks = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i += 200) {
      chunks.push(text.slice(i, i + 200));
    }

    return chunks
      .map(chunk => chunk.join(' '))
      .map(value => (
        <View>
          <Text>{value}</Text>
          <AbMob/>
        </View>
      ));
  }
}
```

This works by putting words into an array (asssuming words are separated by a space), splitting them into chunks of 200 and then joining them back together. The remaining blocks of 200 words are then mapped into your component which has an ad at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I try and I come back to you.

Comment: I get as a result the admob only

Comment: My text tag retun nothing

Comment: The above example does work, you can see a functional version [here.](https://snack.expo.io/@campbellmg/belligerent-nachos) It is likely something wrong with your implementation or style, feel free to update your original question with your code if you want me to have a look.

Comment: The snack I have linked above works on Android, iOS and web. You may be having an issue with scrolling in which case you can put the above component into a scrollview or put the chunk array into a flatlist

Comment: Can you see my code and help me  [here](https://snack.expo.io/@findel/admob-in-text)

Comment: You need to remove the space from this line `return(<View> {this._admobIn()}</View>);`